# Existe alguma área do StackOverflow para estudantes ou iniciantes?

Tags: debate

Existe alguma área do StackOverflow para estudantes ou iniciantes?
Pelo que percebi, de um modo geral, as perguntas de interesse de estudantes e iniciantes não têm recebido boa acolhida. Não sei se existe alguma restrição nas regras para postagem. Gostaria de saber se existe espaço para iniciantes e estudantes (meu caso).

Comment: São bem recebidas sim. Desde que seja uma pergunta, que tenha demonstração de algum esforço, que seja clara e realmente útil. O problema é que é comum iniciantes e principalmente estudantes pedirem para fazer tudo para eles. Ou não conseguem escrever minimamente algo compreensível. Se a pessoa não consegue comunicar minimamente o que ela quer, fica complicado. Muitas vezes a pessoa não quer ajuda para aprender, ele quer ajuda para fazer errado, quer fazer coisas inúteis. Muitos aqui (eu incluso) adoram responder boas perguntas de iniciantes.

Comment: O problema não é se as perguntas são para estudantes ou iniciantes. O problema é que as perguntas permitidas são perguntas técnicas. Ou seja, uma pergunta do tipo "*O meu programa para somar dois números não funciona, e aqui está o código que tentei fazer*" é válida e é uma pergunta de iniciante. Já uma pergunta aberta, vaga e opinativa do tipo "*E aí pessoal, vocês acham melhor trabalhar com Java ou com C#?*" não é legal. Já uma pergunta "*O meu programa não funciona, me ajude*", sem mostrar nenhum código também não dá.

Comment: Veja este exemplo:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5557/como-inicializar-uma-matriz-usando-ponteiros
Foi postada uma pergunta. Vários usuários responderam numa boa, agregando valor à questão. Outros, não. Apenas criticaram, sem ajudar em nada.

Comment: Roberto, migrei sua pergunta aqui pro meta, que é o site onde a gente discute o Stack Overflow em Português. Sobre a pergunta que você linkou acima, você acha ela clara?

Comment: A "pergunta" que você indicou nem sequer é uma pergunta, é uma afirmação. Ele está afirmando que precisa de algo, ou seja, basicamente; "faça para mim".

Comment: Este é um excelente exemplo de como não perguntar. Se é isso o seu desejo, realmente não tem nenhuma área disponível no *site* para isto. Olha essa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43733/101 Quer coisa mais básica que isto? Mas a pergunta foi bem feita. Ele mostrou que não sabe o básico mas mostrou esforço, foi claro, está tentando fazer algo correto, só não sabe como fazer. Todos que responderam lá fizeram um desserviço ao *site* e ao contrário do que se possa imaginar ao autor da pergunta também.

Comment: <desabafo>Ontem mesmo vi uma dessas "perguntas ruins de iniciante". Eu sugeria uma coisa e o autor da pergunta respondia algo do tipo: (1) não precisa mais, vou fazer do meu jeito [errado] mesmo; ou [2] isso eu já sei [ou "já tentei"], o problema é no outro lugar [então por que perguntou A se queria saber B???? Sem falar que a solução de B era igualmente fácil se ele tivesse perguntado desde o começo]</desabafo>

Comment: @marcus totalmente de acordo. Levantei esse problema **[nesta postagem](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2096)**, mas gerou controvérsias, pois algumas pessoas querem aceitar qualquer tipo de coisa aqui no site com "discurso de político". Ainda assim tenho esperança de um dia a comunidade entender que querer abraçar todo mundo não dá, então temos que filtrar o que combina com o que queremos para o site. Sonhar com "um mundo ideal para todos" é bom, mas nem sempre funciona na prática. E se de um jeito ou de outro vai desagradar alguém, prefiro desagradar quem não se empenha.

Comment: O que reparo é que tem muita gente preocupada com o nível das perguntas, mas se esquece de melhorar suas próprias respostas.

Comment: Tenho a impressão de que alguns "experts" que comentaram acima estão, em verdade, desejando "filtrar" as perguntas que não são de seu interesse.
Por isso, retomo a questão inicial: por que não criar uma área própria para iniciantes?

Comment: @RobertoSantos como já comentado por alguns colegas, iniciante é sempre bem vindo. O problema é quando a pessoa não quer aprender e nem fazer certo, o que é uma categoria completamente diferente. Temos perguntas tão básicas a ponto de explicar como funciona IF. Em compensação, temos pessoas querendo fazer coisas complexas e avançadas pegando código pronto, sem a mínima vontade de aprender o essencial. Esse tipo de atitude que complica o site, e não os iniciantes. E outra, o site tem documentação de como perguntar e responder, e um iniciante com vontade provavelmente não vai se opor a estudar.

Comment: Tem gente de todo tipo, mas trocar acusações não vai nos levar a lugar nenhum. Como já disseram, não há nada no site contra iniciantes. Só é importante que a pergunta possa ser respondida objetivamente. E nesse ponto os usuários mais experientes devem tentar orientar os novatos. Na verdade, é comum eles de fato orientarem, mas nem sempre essa orientação é bem-recebida. Tem gente que acha que pode perguntar o que quiser, da maneira que quiser. Isso não pode. Agora, pergunta de iniciante, pode sim.

Comment: Inclusive, vale lembrar que com pouca pontuação, já da pra usar o **[chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910)**, que pode ser usado para assuntos que não caibam no modelo Q&A. Uma lida nas perguntas já feitas no site é um bom indicativo do que é bem aceito, o que não é, e qualquer pergunta básica desde que objetiva já rende os pontos suficientes para comentar em qualquer postagem e participar do chat.

Comment: Tentando ser objetivo: o que você quer perguntar? Você pode editar a pergunta ali em cima descrevendo ou colando a pergunta que quer fazer no site, e o pessoal pode dizer se está no escopo do site, e sugerir melhorias se for o caso

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Roberto, olhe a sua mais recente pergunta:

[Erro de passagem de parâmetro de matriz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43948/132)

Esta pergunta é:

- De nível iniciante;
- Perfeitamente válida e
- Muito bem-vinda.

O que esta pergunta tem de tão diferente de muitas perguntas de nível iniciante que acabam não sendo bem recebidas?

1. **Você explicou o que está tentando fazer.** Há muitas perguntas aqui aonde o autor apenas coloca um monte de código sem maiores explicações ou apenas pede ajuda sem explicar o que está fazendo.
2. **Você explicou o que está dando errado.** Há muitas perguntas aqui aonde o autor apenas diz "*deu erro*", sem dizer qual foi o erro. Ou pior, às vezes nem isso ele diz e espera que nós adivinhemos o que está acontecendo de errado.
3. **Você mostrou o código que você tem.** Há muitas perguntas aqui aonde o autor pede ajuda e diz qual o erro que teve sem mostrar o que foi que ele desenvolveu. Nem todas as perguntas necessariamente devem incluir código, mas neste caso, o autor da pergunta mesmo assim deve demonstrar o que ele está tentando fazer.
4. **A sua pergunta é técnica e pede a solução de um problema.** Há muitas pessoas que vem aqui e postam perguntas abertas, genéricas e opinativas no estilo de "*Qual é melhor, C++ ou Java?*" ou "*Aonde encontro um bom livro de Delphi?*". Estas perguntas abertas, genéricas e opinativas não são bem-vindas aqui porque não há resposta certa ou errada e sim apenas um monte de debate infindável e inconclusivo sobre o tema. O SO.pt **não é** um fórum de debates, para isso existem outros sites.
5. **A sua pergunta demonstra esforço em resolver o problema**, afinal você montou um código e sabe aonde está o problema que você quer solucionar. Há muitas pessoas que vem aqui e apenas pedem "*façam tudo para mim*". Novamente, nem sempre a pergunta necessariamente precisa ter um código, mas demonstrar que você está tentando solucionar o problema, mesmo que não haja nenhum código envolvido, **nos ajuda a ajudar você**.

Como resultado por você ter feito uma pergunta clara, detalhada, esforçada e específica, você rapidamente ganhou uma boa resposta e alguns votos a favor (inclusive o meu). E até o momento você ainda não tem nenhum voto contra (e duvido que terá).

Infelizmente, muitos iniciantes não conhecem ou não seguem ou não sabem seguir os princípios que eu delineei nestes cinco itens acima. E como resultado acabam recebendo votos em contrário, reclamações e têm as suas questões fechadas. Depois eles acabam ficando com a impressão de que esta comunidade não gosta de estudantes e iniciantes, o que não é verdade.

**Se um estudante ou iniciante postar uma pergunta que esteja de acordo com os cinco itens que eu delineei acima, eu tenho certeza que ela será bem recebida.**

Comment: Agradeço a todos os que me orientaram, em especial ao Victor e ao Bigown.
Entendo que há necessidade de observância de regras de postagem, para que o portal não vire uma bagunça. 
Algumas perguntas consideradas triviais por profissionais podem ser totalmente relevantes para estudantes. Por isso é que expus meu apelo de maior tolerância com iniciantes, sobretudo com quem ainda não está adaptado às regras do fórum.

Comment: @RobertoSantos Para registrar: fico feliz que tenha dado tudo certo, que você tenha feito a pergunta e que sua dúvida tenha sido resolvida. Espero que tenha se sentido bem recebido no site!

Comment: Grato, Bfavaretto e demais colaboradores!